# iPhone real world application tutorial

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Can anyone suggest to me a book, video, or website that offers instructions on building a real world application for the iPhone. I've seen many bits and pieces but I'm looking for a resource that puts it all together into one working application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: hey! While I was typing my short answer, 3 others posted answers! Isn't SO great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stanford iphone class is great. There are slides, videos, sample code and good guide for a complicated project.
You can view it on iTunes U
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

Answer (score 2):

You could try [the iPhone developer](http://www.theiphonedev.com/SourceCode/tabid/143/Default.aspx) for source code.

Answer (score 1):

This site has a lot of good examples.  I don't know if you'd call them full apps, but they show you how to do a lot of things:  http://appsamuck.com/

Answer (score 1):

I've really enjoyed [Head First iPhone Development](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfiphonedev/), though the current edition is a little out-of-date. There'll be a [new release this year](http://www.amazon.ca/Head-First-iPhone-iPad-Development/dp/1449387829), with iOS 4 and iPad coverage (which might be out-of-date by the time it's released, if iOS 5 SDK hints at being released sometime this year to Paid Registered Apple Developers)

Edit : The new release is out. Second Edition. Covers XCode 4.2 and everything you could possibly need :)

Answer (score 1):

The [Big Nerd Ranch Guide](http://www.amazon.co.uk/IPhone-Programming-Ranch-Guide-Guides/dp/0321706242/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1306258278&sr=1-1) is an excellent book that will take you from start to competent enough to look things up yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have some programming experience I can't recommend 'Head First iPhone Development' enough. It's more of a book with puzzles and questions to be answered while its walking you through creating actual applications. Cocoa Touch and Objective-C didn't start clicking until I had finished this book.